# What IAM action is required to upload to another account's S3 bucket with an ACL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I currently have two AWS accounts, A and B. There is an S3 bucket X that is owned by B. A has been granted permissions to write to the bucket.

The following command works fine from account A:

```
aws s3 cp Foo s3://X/bot/test/Foo
```

Unfortunately, this command has the downside that the object lives in B's bucket but B cannot do anything with it. I learned from a different SO post that the way to correct this is to run the following command instead:

```
aws s3 cp Foo s3://X/bot/test/Foo --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

This command works with the intended effect when I use a role with root privileges inside account A. However, I am delegating the privilege to a role with only the following four actions on the bucket.

```
           "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject"
```

When this role is assumed and I try to run the command with `--acl` flag, I get the following error:

```
upload failed: ./Foo to s3://X/bot/test/Foo An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Note that the command works fine from the role without the `--acl` flag.

**What additionally actions do I need to grant to the role to allow it to execute the `s3 cp` command with the `--acl` flag?**

Comment: Try adding s3:PutObjectAcl or using s3:PutObject*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [AWS CLI S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html):

> Note that if you're using the --acl option, ensure that any associated
>   IAM policies include the **"s3:PutObjectAcl"** action.

Example Policy :

```
{
    "UserName": "myuser",
    "PolicyName": "mypolicy",
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Sid": "Stmt1234567891234"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```